# (perl) Rename bulk files - moving section starting with #{NUMBER} to front

Tags: scripting, terminal, perl, rename

I am trying to rename many files with the example formatting using rename with perl scripting

```
'Balisong Tutorial - (0g Chaplin) - Advanced #21-d8ajkHL34s0.mkv'
'Balisong Tutorial - (ALT Reverse Behind the 8 Ball) - Advanced #1-vpDt7sdYwpQ.webm'
'Balisong Tutorial - (Around the Twirld) - Advanced #16--BEi7dyGJkI.mkv'
'Balisong Tutorial - (Around the World) - Advanced #7-doEKZCCqfDY.mkv'
'Balisong Tutorial - (Backhand Catch) - Advanced #29-ETHKZZ6cKWc.mkv'
'Balisong Tutorial - (Blender) - Advanced #6-7nR3_Z2HkbM.mkv'
```

The first title

> Balisong Tutorial - (0g Chaplin) - Advanced #21-d8ajkHL34s0.mkv

How can I move the #21 to the front to appear like this

> #21 Balisong Tutorial - (0g Chaplin) - Advanced d8ajkHL34s0.mkv

I am unfortunately unfamiliar with Sed and do not know how to accomplish this with rename.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated. If at all possible, I would be very grateful for a small explanation of the syntax used. I know the example here is sort of silly but would still be beneficial to understand the solution for future circumstances.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you want to rename files, then it's better to use the `rename` utility.

Comment: What should happen to the dashes? in particular, what should happen when the digits are followed by more than a single dash (as in `Advanced #16--BEi7dyGJkI.mkv`)?

Comment: @steeldriver It actually does not matter, the only objective in this case is to move the #16 to the front - everything else can stay where it is or be deleted. appreciate the probing question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the perl-based `rename` command, you could capture

1. everything up to the `#`
2. the `#` and one or more following digits

then optionally match but not capture one or more dashes; then substitute the captured substrings back in the opposite order:

```
$ rename -n 's/(.*)(#\d+)-+/$2 $1/' *.mkv
rename(Balisong Tutorial - (0g Chaplin) - Advanced #21-d8ajkHL34s0.mkv, #21 Balisong Tutorial - (0g Chaplin) - Advanced d8ajkHL34s0.mkv)
rename(Balisong Tutorial - (Around the Twirld) - Advanced #16--BEi7dyGJkI.mkv, #16 Balisong Tutorial - (Around the Twirld) - Advanced BEi7dyGJkI.mkv)
rename(Balisong Tutorial - (Around the World) - Advanced #7-doEKZCCqfDY.mkv, #7 Balisong Tutorial - (Around the World) - Advanced doEKZCCqfDY.mkv)
rename(Balisong Tutorial - (Backhand Catch) - Advanced #29-ETHKZZ6cKWc.mkv, #29 Balisong Tutorial - (Backhand Catch) - Advanced ETHKZZ6cKWc.mkv)
rename(Balisong Tutorial - (Blender) - Advanced #6-7nR3_Z2HkbM.mkv, #6 Balisong Tutorial - (Blender) - Advanced 7nR3_Z2HkbM.mkv)
```

Remove the `-n` when you are satisfied with the suggested transformations.

Comment: Ah! Excellent! Thank you @steeldriver :D

Comment: At first, I didn't get what `$1` and `$2` are, and where they come from.
But reading it a few times helped.
So, `(.*)` is magically *captured* in `$1`, and `(#\d+)` is captured in `$2`.
Therefore, `$2 $1` produces the desired new file name(s).
Thanks!

Comment: @Henke-Нава́льныйПсм yes that's it - see for example [Grouping & Capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)